# determinant of normal bundle ample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety over $k$ and $Y$ a smooth closed subvariety of codimension r. Let $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ be the rank r normal bundle. Is it possible to determine when $\mathrm{det}\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ ?

Comment: Do you know the adjunction formula?

Comment: I am interested in the problem under what kind of assumptions $\mathrm{det}\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is ample?

Comment: Dear user45766, ok. That seems like quite a different (and much more focused) question. You might consider editing your question to clarify this.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want $X$ to be a surface, and $Y$ a curve? Then of course $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is ample iff $Y^2>0$.  Please edit your question so that it makes reasonable sense (or delete it).

Comment: @abx: I think there is a precise question here, "Is there any smooth projective variety $X$ other than $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that for every smooth subvariety $Y$, $\text{det}\ \mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is ample?"

Comment: @user45766: It is extremely unpleasant that you have  completely deleted the original question which just asked for a formula for the determinant of the normal bundle. I have given you  precisely such a formula , but now my answer looks like a complete *non sequitur* because of your modifications. Please modify your post in order that the original question is re-established and add your question on ampleness below.

Comment: @Jason Starr. A simple abelian variety has that property.

Answer (score 3):

Given an exact sequence of locally free sheaves $0\to E'\to E\to E''\to 0$ on, say, a ringed space,  there is a canonical isomorphism $\text {det} E=\text {det} E'\otimes \text {det} E''$: this is pure multilinear algebra.
Now in your situation apply this to the exact sequence defining the normal bundle $$ 0\to T_Y\to T_X|Y \to N_{Y/X}\to 0$$ and get $\text {det} (T_X|Y)=\text {det} T_Y\otimes \text {det} N_{Y/X}$.
From this you obtain your required formula $$\text {det} N_{Y/X}=\text {det} T_X|Y \otimes \text {det} T_Y^*$$.
Classically geometers express this in terms of canonical bundles $K_X=\text {det}\: T_X^*, K_Y=\text {det}\: T_Y^*$ as $$K_Y=K_X|Y\otimes \text {det} N_{Y/X}$$ This is the adjunction formula mentioned by Artie: I wrote this answer to show that  it is a triviality!

Comment: This is an answer to the original question which just asked for a formula for the determinant, and I gave such a formula  here . The original question did not even mention the word "ample" !

Comment: The more interesting question is under what kind of assumptions $\mathrm{det}\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is ample ? As far as I know for $X$ a projective space this is true, but what is for example for Hirzebruch surfaces or $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Well that new  question may be more interesting but it is not what you asked originally.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the question is somewhat imprecise.  Here is one precise formulation (of course I do not know if this is what the OP has in mind): "Is there any smooth projective variety $X$ other than $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that for every smooth subvariety $Y$, $\text{det}\ \mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is ample?"  The OP asks about $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ or other Hirzebruch surfaces.  Of course these varieties fail the condition.  In general, if $f:X\to Z$ is a fiber-type contraction and if $Y\subset X$ is a general fiber, then $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$ is $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus r}$ where $r$ equals $\text{dim}(Z)$.  So for any $X$ as above, $X$ admits no fiber-type contraction.  If one allows $Y$ to be somewhat singular, probably one can rule out *all* contractions.

Comment: Good question, but I am not sure there is a reasonable answer. For instance, an abelian variety will have this property if and only if it is simple.